# The equation of base of an equilateral triangle is $x+y=2$ and the vertex is $(2,-1)$, then find the length of side of the triangle.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, triangles

The equation of base of an equilateral triangle is $x+y=2$ and the vertex is $(2,-1)$, then find the length of side of the triangle.

My Attempt :

Equation of one of the sides can be obtained as :

$$y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$$
$$y+1=\tan (60) (x-2)$$
$$y+1=\sqrt {3} (x-2)$$
$$\sqrt {3}x - y -3=0$$

Comment: Try dropping a perpendicular from the vertex to the base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a$ be the length of each side of the equilateral triangle.
[image]

Given line is $x+y-2=0$

Let $d$ be the perpendicular distance from $(2,-1)$ onto  the line $x+y-2=0$
$$d=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

So, the perpendicular height of the triangle is $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Now consider the one of the half side of the equilateral triangle.

According to pythagoras theorem we get,
$$a^2=\frac{a^2}{4}+\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2$$
$$\frac{3a^2}{4}=\frac12$$
$$a=\sqrt{\frac 23}$$
Therefore, the length of the side of the triangle is $\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{3}}$